# How to merge two Maps properly?

Tags: kotlin

I've been trying to solve a problem, where I should merge two Maps to get the new one with no equal values for equal keys.

```
fun main() {
    mergePhoneBooks(mapOf("Emergency" to "112"),
        mapOf("Emergency" to "911", "Police" to "02"))
}
fun mergePhoneBooks(mapA: Map<String, String>, mapB: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String> {
    val result = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    for ((keyA, valueA) in mapA) {
        for ((keyB, valueB) in mapB) {
            result[keyA] = valueA
            result[keyB] = valueB
            if (keyA == keyB) {
                if (valueA != valueB) {
                    result[keyA] = "$valueA, $valueB"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    println(result)
    return result
}
```

What I need is:

```
{Emergency=112, 911, Police=02},
```

but all I get is:

```
{Emergency=112, Police=02}
```

Comment: You might find it easier (or at least, more elegant) if your map values are `Set<String>`s, with each number as a separate String, instead of storing them as comma-separated combined Strings.  That's likely to make it much easier to handle cases such as where the second map has a value that shares _some_ of the same numbers as the first — especially if they're ordered differently.  You could then concatenate them to a single String (in whatever order you prefer), e.g. using `joinToString()`, when you display/process them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fun main() {
    val m1 = mapOf("Emergency" to "112")
    val m2 = mapOf("Emergency" to "911", "Police" to "02")
    val r = (m1.entries + m2.entries).groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
    // or use Sequence 
    // val r = (m1.asSequence() + m2.asSequence()).distinct().groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
    println(r) // {Emergency=[112, 911], Police=[02]}
    println(r.mapValues { it.value.joinToString(", ") }) // {Emergency=112, 911, Police=02}
}
```

Comment: the point is that the returning type is Map<String, String>, not Map<String, List<String>>, so it is a good solution, but not for this concrete problem

Comment: @ladamengh `r.mapValues { it.value.joinToString(", ") }` returns `Map<String, String>`

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
result[keyA] = valueA
result[keyB] = valueB
```

You've assigned the `valueB` to the key (if keyA was same as keyB) again so the condition `if (valueA != valueB) {` is never going to be true.

You should remove the above lines and do it like this:

```kotlin
if (keyA == keyB && valueA != valueB) {
    result[keyA] = "$valueA, $valueB"
} else {
    result[keyA] = valueA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below code will solve your issue:

```
fun main() {
    val first = mapOf("A" to "0", "B" to "1", "C" to "2")
    val second = mapOf("A" to "4", "C" to "2")

    val result = (first.asSequence() + second.asSequence()).distinct()
                    .groupBy({ it.key }, { it.value })
                    .mapValues { it.value.joinToString(",") }

    print(result)           // {A=0,4, B=1, C=2}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A map can only have one value per key. If you need to preserve multiple values, you need to change the value type to something like a List or Pair.

```
fun <K, V> mergeMapsValues(mapA: Map<K, V>, mapB: Map<K, V>): Map<K, List<V>> {
    val outMap = mapA.mapValues { (_, value) -> mutableListOf(value) }.toMutableMap()
    mapB.forEach { (key, value) ->
        outMap.getOrPut(key, ::mutableListOf).add(value)
    }
    return outMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `mergeWith` extension function:

```
infix fun Map<String, String>.mergeWith(anotherMap: Map<String, String>): Map<String, String> {
    return (keys + anotherMap.keys).associateWith {
        setOf(this[it], anotherMap[it]).filterNotNull().joinToString()
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
val mapC = mapA mergeWith mapB
```